# How can i extract the two max values for each rows of my Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I extract the two max values for each rows of my Dataframe?

```
Date        gld        tlt        qqq
2012-01-31  NaN        NaN        NaN
2012-02-29  -0.064527  0.391660   -0.071191
2012-03-31  -0.064527  0.391660   -0.071191
2012-04-30  0.025958   -0.009515  0.145537
2012-05-31  -0.292595  -0.395539  0.538963
2012-06-30  -0.292595  -0.395539  0.538963
2012-07-31  0.055247   0.067361   0.235317
2012-08-31  0.441790   0.280636   -0.070989
2012-09-30  0.441790   0.280636   -0.070989
2012-10-31  -0.236148  -0.126485  -0.021196
2012-11-30  -0.021589  0.032538   0.083634
```

I want to create a new one that has for each date the one or two highest values!

I would have a new data frame like this:

```
Date           gld       tlt       qqq
2012-02-29     nan       0.391660  nan
2012-03-31     nan       0.391660  nan
2012-04-30     nan       nan       0.145537
2012-05-31     nan       nan       0.538963
2012-08-31     0.441790  nan       nan
```

Comment: What do you mean by "one or two" highest values? Your desired output shows only one value per row. What determines whether two values will be desired for any given row?

Comment: What @FedericoS says, and what happend to the rest of the rows? For example date `2012-11-30`?

Comment: Hi federico! I mean that I can have n columns (maybe 20 differents stocks) and I want to create a new dataframe with the columns that has n max values for each  rows(can be 1,3 or 10)!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def func(x):
    x[[c for c in x.index.to_list() if c != np.argmax(x)]] = np.NaN
    return x

df[['gld', 'tlt', 'qqq']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: doesnt't work, gives invalid character in identifier

Comment: For me , it was working perfectly fine on posted dataframe.., could please post the exact  error?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to show the top `l` values **per row**, I'd recommend:

```
l = 2

df.where(df.rank(axis = 1, ascending=False, method='dense') <= l)
```

Output (with `l=2`):

```
                 gld       tlt       qqq
Date                                    
2012-02-29 -0.064527  0.391660       NaN
2012-03-31 -0.064527  0.391660       NaN
2012-04-30  0.025958       NaN  0.145537
2012-05-31 -0.292595       NaN  0.538963
2012-06-30 -0.292595       NaN  0.538963
2012-07-31       NaN  0.067361  0.235317
2012-08-31  0.441790  0.280636       NaN
2012-09-30  0.441790  0.280636       NaN
2012-10-31       NaN -0.126485 -0.021196
2012-11-30       NaN  0.032538  0.083634
```

Comment: Hi Ecortazar, it doesnt't work. It give the rows with the max values of all the the dataframe. But i need the same number of rows of the original one with the largest values I set( 1 or 2) .

Comment: @AntonioZanolin. I think your explanation is a bit confusing. I've amended the example to work on a per row basis instead of a per column basis and to take the top L values in each. Hope this is what you are looking for.